# I can't find the main verb here

Tags: verbs

> Whatever I have up till now accepted as most true and assured I have gotten either from the senses or through the senses.

What does this sentence mean? I can't find the main verb here.

Comment: DIRECT OBJECT: "Whatever ... assured" SUBJECT: "I" VERB: "have gotten"

Comment: @Araucaria: It's not an adjunct in OP's context, ***whatever*** you might say! :) Terminology isn't my strong suit, but it's probably a relative determiner/pronoun. It's obviously some kind of "nouny" thing, since it's definitely serving as an "object" in OP's text (not in mine though).

Comment: @FumbleFingers No the whole clause *whatever I have .... assured* is an adjunct (adverbial in your terminology, I believe) :)

Comment: @Araucaria: In my understanding, an "adjunct" is an ***optional*** component. That seems to me to be basic vocabulary, not specialist terminology. But in constructions like *Whatever I have I owe to you* the direct object *(whatever I have)* is required, not optional.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Hmm, I need to think about that. EDIT: Yes, FF, you're right ... at least on one analysis of the sentence, but maybe altogether :)

Comment: @StoneyB Hmm, think you might be right. Have deleted my comment!

Comment: @Araucaria You were misled --as OP was confused-- by the OSV construction.

Comment: @StoneyB Hmm, maybe, but not necessarily. Depends on what you think about gapping in the main clause.

Comment: @Araucaria I think this *whatever* = "everything, all"; there's no interrogative sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following shows the main verb in bold, and helps demonstrate the meaning of the sentence through added punctuation and rewording.

Add punctuation:

> Whatever I have (up till now) accepted as, "most true and assured",
>   I **have gotten** either from the senses or through the senses.

Rearrange and reword:

> Until now, all the things that I have accepted as reality,
>   I **have gotten** either from the senses or through the senses.

Simplify language:

> Until now, what I considered to be true and real
>   **was based** on the senses--either directly or indirectly.

Comment: Why the downvote? This answer appears to me to be a very clear and straightforward way of helping someone see what the original sentence says and how it says it.

Comment: @BenKovitz - Thanks!  Riddle: Having a downvote applied to this answer makes it even better. Why?

Comment: The glory of triumphing over the forces of darkness?

Comment: @BenKovitz Nope! The value of accepting criticism: the downvote came before I improved the answer, and the improved answer is the one you like. Granted, I worded the riddle specifically to throw you off the presumed time-line of events; compare if I had said, the downvote *made* it better.  All's fair in love and riddles.  :)

Comment: Hooray, the system worked! :) I gave your answer a +1 the instant I read it. Now that I've looked at the edit history, indeed I see what an improvement it was to explicitly point out the main verb.

Comment: @BenKovitz - Thank you for the fine copy editing, and I'm OK with such, but I do ask if something seems questionable (you put question marks in the edit comment!) or central to the answer to please discuss in comments first.

Comment: @BenKovitz - Rolled back.  Note that I considered the possibility of highlighting ***was based on*** as a [phrasal verb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phrasal_verb), but decided not to go there. That adds complexity to the answer and then one has to make the comparison with "have gotten from".  It might be considered a phrasal verb, but IMO it's a weak one at best--more like a collocation. The final decision was simplicity in order to focus on the main-verb.

Comment: Sounds good. Determining what should be most salient and what should be in the background is always a judgement call—and always a very important part of writing answers on ELL.

Answer (score 1):

*Have gotten* is the primary verb. To reorder the sentence, *I have gotten [everything I have up till now accepted as most true and assured] from the senses.*